# adding a new contact information in txt file

Tags: python, hash

I have this long python code and I'm having trouble finishing or fixing it and I need help.

First I have these codes -

This will just display the menus and i have created several def functions. One is for creating data and saving to the txt file, and the other is to use a hash function to split the name. Contact info as data is created in the txt file. Finally, in a while loop I have to somehow call up the menu codes and this is where I get stuck, or I may need to fix the whole thing. Also when I put a phone number in like 555-5555, it makes an error. How would I input a number like this value?

```
def menu():
    print("Contact List Menu:\n")
    print("1. Add a Contact")
    print("2. Display Contacts")
    print("3. Exit\n")
menu()
choice = int(input("What would you like to do?: "))

def data():
    foo = open("foo.txt", "a+")
    name = input("enter name: ")
    number = int(input("enter the number: "))
    foo.write(name + " " + str(number))
foo.close()


def contact():
    data = open("foo.txt")
    file = {}
    for person in data:
        (Id, number) = person.split()
        file[number] = Id
data.close()

while choice !=3:
    if choice == 1:
        print(data())
    if choice ==2:
        print(data())
    menu()
    choice = int(input("What would you like to do?: "))
```

It seems that the program never stops and I have to use option 3 from the menu to exit the program.

Comment: if you have errors, it is usually recommended that you show the stack trace and error description...

Comment: nevermind, i fixed the error, i just removed the int function on the def data funnction code. but still having the same problem with the while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phone number like `555-5555` is not valid integer number so keep it as a text.

Inside `menu()` you call `menu()` which call `menu()`, etc. It is recursion. When you choose `3` you leave last `menu()` and return to previous `menu()`.

---

**EDIT:**

btw: you have to add "\n" in `write`

```
def menu():
    print("Contact List Menu:\n")
    print("1. Add a Contact")
    print("2. Display Contacts")
    print("3. Exit\n")

def data():
    foo = open("foo.txt", "a+")
    name = input("enter name: ")
    number = int(input("enter the number: "))
    foo.write(name + " " + str(number) + "\n") # new line
    foo.close()

def contact():
    data = open("foo.txt")
    for person in data:
        name, number = person.split()
        print(name, number)
    data.close()

#----------------

menu()
choice = int(input("What would you like to do?: "))

while choice !=3:

    if choice == 1:
        data()
    if choice == 2:
        contact()

    menu()
    choice = int(input("What would you like to do?: "))
```

Comment: yeah i can press 3 and i can exit the program, but i can't figure out how to use other option from when i press 2, i can't get to option 2

Comment: when you press `2` you call `data()` not `contact()` - you call wrong function.

Comment: so what would i have to do in the while loop if i want to display contacts?

Comment: ahh thank you for the fix, but however i don'tk now why it won't display anything on option 2 for some reason

Comment: do you get error or something ? first delete old file `foo.txt` because there is no "\n" at the end of every contact so `for person in data` reads everything as one line. Then add new contacts.

Comment: no error, just doesn't display nothing, it goes back to the contact list menu screen... strange

Comment: Do you have any contact in `foo.txt` ? If `foo.txt` is empty then you can't see contacts on the screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95515/discussion-between-kee23-and-furas).